# FB.api query return empty result only on Firefox

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, firefox, facebook-apps

Im using FB.api query to fetch a user friends list (that already using my app).
This worked till today, now it continue to work in every browser but Firefox, in Firefox the response return "Unknown Error".

```
    FB.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
    query: 'SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE has_added_app=1 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = ' + user_facebook_id+ ')'
    }, function (response) {

    }
```

I have noticed that facebook perform this http call:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=.....`

And its response is:

SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone.

I guess that this problem is due to facebook api security update, my question is how to solve it and why it happens only in Firefox?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you get this sorted out? I have a similar issue